# Error: "The name 'mygrid' does not exist in the current context" when creating a Windows Docker image for .NET Framework 4.8 web API with XAML comp

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, docker, .net-4.8

I have encountered an issue while creating a Windows Docker image for my .NET Framework 4.8 web API solution. The solution includes a class library that references a XAML component, similar to WPF XAML, which contains a DataGrid defined within it.

When running the application locally, everything works fine, and the DataGrid with the name 'mygrid' is accessible in the XAML.cs file. However, during the creation of the Docker image, I receive the error message: "The name 'mygrid' does not exist in the current context." This error seems to occur because the DataGrid is defined within the XAML file and not in the corresponding XAML.cs file.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully create a Docker image for my .NET Framework 4.8 web API solution without encountering the "The name 'mygrid' does not exist in the current context" error.

Any suggestions, insights, or alternative approaches to ensure the DataGrid is recognized in the XAML.cs file when building the Docker image would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How do you build the code in the container, especially  the XAML part? And why do you want a `DataGrid` in a Docker container?

Comment: we are creating a report and we load the window that has datagrid into the pdf report

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're missing MSBuild stuff which causes the WPF code generation to trigger. You may need to have the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop` VS workload installed in the SDK image.

Try this in your Dockerfile within the SDK stage:

```
RUN curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe && \
    (start /w vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache modify \
    --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop) && \
    del /q vs_buildtools.exe
```

But stepping back a bit. You can't make use of a UI in a Docker container. Does your Web API actually require the DataGrid? If not, you may want to consider refactoring your code so that the class library depended upon by Web API project doesn't include the WPF components. In other words, refactor the WPF components into their own library separate from the business logic.